# How to make a Generic compareTo without Warnings?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings, comparable

I'm making the method belong:

```
public static <T> int compareTo(Comparable<T> o1,Comparable<T> o2){

        if(o1==o2){
            //Equals
            return 0;
        }else if(o1!=null && o2!=null){
            //Comparation 
            return o1.compareTo((T) o2);
        }else{
            //Not equals
            return (o1==null?-1:1);
        }               

    }
```

But Eclipse shows me the Warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Comparable to T

How can I write this generic method without warnings?

Comment: which line shows the warning ?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI I would guess this line "return o1.compareTo((T) o2);" but not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compareTo(T o1,T o2){

    if(o1==o2){
        //Equals
        return 0;
    }else if(o1!=null && o2!=null){
        //Comparation 
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }else{
        //Not equals
        return (o1==null?-1:1);
    }               

}
```

Comment: Would be even better to use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @JB Nizet, no, usually it's better to avoid wildcards, because it's usually bad to compare objects of different types.

Answer (score 0):

The most general would be

```
public static <T> int compareTo(Comparable<T> o1, T o2){

    if(o1==o2){
        //Equals
        return 0;
    }else if(o1!=null && o2!=null){
        //Comparation 
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }else{
        //Not equals
        return (o1==null?-1:1);
    }               

}
```

It works even for types that are comparable to other types.